# How to get data account from an instruction?

Tags: anchor

Hi i have a UserAccount which is used to hold the data of the user and is created with a instruction called sign_up , and also i have a setup_game instruction and in there I want to check that is there a user registered with the given Pubkey.
In TS tests to do that i use :

```
const account = await program.account.userAccount.fetch(
            secondUser.publicKey
        );
```

So this gives the user_account of that Pubkey .
And my Rust code so far :

```
pub fn setup_game(ctx: Context<SetupGame>, player_two: Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
    ctx.accounts
        .game
        .start([ctx.accounts.player_one.key(), player_two])
}
```

Comment: Based on the code provided, could you clarify what you're asking? you want to check that `account` belongs to a registered user?

Comment: Actually i want to check if any user with Pubkey has the UserAccount or not (registered or not ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On solana, for you to read/write to an account, it needs to be passed as an account to the instruction.

So if you want to read the account that belongs to `player_two`, you'll need to pass it as an account to the `SetupGame` instruction.

So you'll have access to the account info of `ctx.accounts.player_two` if its initialized

Comment: Thanks, but do you see the code 
```const account = await program.account.userAccount.fetch(
            secondUser.publicKey
        ); ``` i want the rust code of it .
Actually by registered i mean the UserAccount of Pubkey .

Comment: Oh, I think I understand your question now. Sure will modify

Comment: Could you edit your question and add in the rust code you have for setup_game

Comment: Of course, I edited it . However I don't know why you asked .

Comment: It helps me to answer your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138527/discussion-between-reza-aslejeddian-and-c-og).